# Catching Same IOException Inside Catch IOException Block

Tags: java, android, exception, try-catch, ioexception

My Android code is behaving funny.  The input stream should and does throw an IOException, which correctly causes control to go to `// read an error stream`. The error stream is read correctly and the debugger steps to `return error_message` with the `error_message` variable containing expected characters read from error stream. It then correctly steps to the `// no op` in the `finally` block, which I added just for kicks.

And then, it steps to `return "all hope lost";`!! Which then, instead of returning to the caller, steps into some Android system code that throws a `SecurityException` with a message about lack of content permissions.

Removing the `finally` block has no impact -- the bug still happens.  The streams being read are from an HTTP URL Connection. No problems if server returns `200` but if server returns `400` it goes through the weird path described above and tries to throw the weird SecurityException.

```
try {
  // read an input stream into message
  return message;
} catch (IOException outer) {
  try {
    // read an error stream into error_message
    return error_message;
  } catch (IOException inner) {
    return "all hope lost";
  }
} finally {
  // no op, just to step debugger
}
```

**Update:** Posting exact code and debug trace.

```
try {
  /*x*/ BufferedReader buffered_reader = 
        new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(
        new BufferedInputStream(http_url_connection.getInputStream())));
  StringBuilder string_builder = new StringBuilder();
  String line;
  for (line = buffered_reader.readLine(); 
       line != null; 
       line = buffered_reader.readLine()) {
    string_builder.append(line);
  }
  return string_builder.toString();
} catch (IOException io_exception) {
  this.io_exception = io_exception;
  BufferedReader buffered_reader = 
       new BufferedReader(
       new InputStreamReader(
       new BufferedInputStream(http_url_connection.getErrorStream())));
  StringBuilder string_builder = new StringBuilder();
  try {
    for (String line = buffered_reader.readLine(); 
         line != null; 
         line = buffered_reader.readLine()) {
      string_builder.append(line);
    }
    /*y*/ String error_message = "server error: " + string_builder.toString();
    return error_message;
  } catch (IOException exception) {
    String level_2_error_message = "level 2 error: " + exception.getMessage();
    return level_2_error_message;
  } finally {
    return "foo";
  }
}
```

Line `/*x*/` causes the jump to the first `catch` as expected. All lines up to `/*y*/` are then executed as expected. Then the **weird** thing is that line `/*y*/` does not complete and control immediately goes to either the next `catch` block if there is no `finally` or to the `finally`. If there is a `finally` then it does not to got the last `catch` block.

The contents of the string buffer on `/*y*/` line look perfectly fine -- a 20 character string from the server.

Comment: You do realize instead of this try-catch madness you could just do something like `Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error in method insertMethodNameHere()", exception);` and that way you actually know what went wrong, right?

Comment: @Zhuinden it is not for debugging. the exceptions are from a network connection and could happen while the user is using the app in the field. so i don't see how `Log.e(...)` would help.

Comment: and if in the final block you place a return statement the behaviour is still the same?

Comment: @eldjon yes, it is still the same. but i have an update to the question. posting exact code and trace.

Comment: if you don't know the actual error, it's hard to find the cause.

Comment: @Zhuinden yes, I might have to reduce this to a self-contained example.

Comment: try to close each stream at finally block. it might have to do with stream not closed.

Comment: @eldjon thanks for the great suggestion. i'll try it out later today and post the results here.

Answer (score 1):

You say that an exception is being thrown by line `/* y */`

By my reading of that line of code, the following are plausible explanations:

- The exception is a `NullPointerException` because `string_builder` is `null`.  But it can't be.
- The exception is an `OutOfMemoryError` because you don't have enough free space for the `toString()` call to create the new `String` object.
- It is possible that `StringBuilder` is not `java.lang.StringBuilder` but some class you wrote yourself.  In that case, any exception is possible.

However, I can't see how you would end up in the second `IOException` handler.

---

Apart from that, the only other *likely* explanation is that that source code does not match the code that you are actually executing; e.g. you forgot to recompile something, or you forgot to redeploy after your last compilation.

---

For what it is worth, your `return` in your `finally` is almost certainly a mistake.

- It means that you will return `"foo"` instead of either of the error messages.
- If (for example) `string_builder.toString()` did throw an NPE or OOME, then the `return` would *squash* it.

A `finally` with a `return` can have non-intuitive behaviour.  It is certainly NOT something you should do "for debugging"!!!

Comment: +1 thanks for the great suggestions. The stringbuilder was perfectly fine as far as NPE & OOME. I stepped through it. Yes, the `return "foo"` is wrong. I tried it both with and without. will update after some more sleuthing.